# Duplicates in Product matrix

Tags: matlab

My goal is to make my values in my matrix unique.

Here is a image of my end product

[image: Matrix Duplicates]

I have tried debugging this but cant seem to understand what is going wrong

So there will only be one [17;4] one [17;7] and so on

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unique` with the `'rows'` input. In this case you want unique columns, so you have to transpose the input and output using `.'`.

```
M = [7 7 7 7 8 8; 
     4 4 4 7 9 9]; % dummy data

M = unique( M.', 'rows', 'stable' ).'; % unique columns, without sorting

% Out: [7 7 8
%       4 7 9]
```

You need the `'stable'` input to avoid sorting numerically, you can omit it if you don't care about that.